# Firefox creating problem in update

Tags: package-management, firefox, snap, squashfs

I see below error when I upgraded from ubuntu 21.10 to ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I see a constant icon on notification area reminging me of something went wrong while update. When I try to update (as it ask) I get below error.

```
The Package system is Broken

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

firefox-locale-en: Depends: firefox (>= 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2) but 99.0+build2-0ubuntu0.21.10.2 is installed
```

I had two version of firefox one from `apt` and another from `snap`. I uninstall the one from `apt` but I can't uninstall the `snap` one. While removing the the `apt` one I removed the firefox directory like `~/.mozilla` and `/etc/firefox` and `/usr/lib/firefox/` and `/usr/lib/firefox-addons/`  along with `sudo apt-get purge firefox`

```
sudo snap uninstall firefox

error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using
       "squashfs": mount: /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-2641143541: wrong fs type, bad
       option, bad superblock on /dev/loop23, missing codepage or helper
       program, or other error.
```

Result of Update and Fixing broken packages

```
$ apt list --upgradable -a 
Listing... Done firefox/jammy 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 99.0+build2-0ubuntu0.21.10.2] firefox/now 99.0+build2-0ubuntu0.21.10.2 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2]
```

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install

=> Installing the firefox snap
==> Installing the firefox snap
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-2641143541: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop23,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_1%3a1snap1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new firefox package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/firefox doesn't exist
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed firefox package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_1%3a1snap1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: @guiverc I updated the version. Thanks the pervious version was 21.10. I regulary takes the updates as they become available.

Comment: I would login to a text terminal and  `sudo apt update` & read the output looking for any clues. I assume you've rebooted since you performed the `do-release-upgrade`, but assuming the output of `apt update` looked as expected; I'd perform `sudo apt full-upgrade` and ensure all packages upgrade. From what you've described I'd expect it to work, OR provide errors/warnings/suggestions which I'd use to work out what I did next. Your paste shows a 21.04/impish package still where it should have been replaced with `firefox-locale-en | 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2              | jammy/universe   | all`

Comment: @guiverc I update the output of update and fix broken in the question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your output shows that the apt problem is merely a symptom of a filesystem/snapd problem. That might, in turn, be a symptom of a disk error or some other problem. Are you using any unusual filesystems? Are any of your partitions full? Do you have any other filesystem or disk-related problems? Are you having any other problems with snaps?

Comment: @user535733, no I don't have any. Everything is running smooth in OS. Let me know if I should check it via some way.